# JavaScript / JQuery to check the child controls of a top level control in Nested repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my page I used nested Repeater with four levels. each level is having CheckBoxList as shown in the image.

[image]

The scenario is when I check/select a top level checkbox item then the child level CheckBoxList item should be checked/seleted, Suppose if I select a Country level (Canada) CheckBoxList item (Create), then all the state's and Cities of the Country's "Create" check box item should be checked. same as shown below image. same applies to the state and its cities. If only a state's list item is selected, its all city's same list item should be checked.

Please help me get this scenario at client side itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could take advantage of additional classes to make easier the selection.

Add accordingly specific classes to each `checkBox`. Something like `continent`, `country`, `state`, `city`. Add also accordingly another class of type `create`, `modify`, `delete`, `view` to each `listItem`.

With jQuery (or your favorite library), catch the `click` handler. Inside the handler select the element based on their class. For the `create` action:

```
$('#yourTopDiv').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
 var isCreateAction = $(this).is('.create'); //or modify, delete, view
 $(this).find('.create').trigger('click'); //goes n levels down in the tree
})
```

Comment: It is a CheckBoxList with list items. Create, Modify, Delete, View.

Comment: Answer updated. Basically add a specific class to each listItem

Comment: Thank you @roland, But I am new to the development, could you please explain it in more detail. or send me the related links.

Comment: The visual designer provides an interface to do standard operations such as adding a class to ListItem or other controls. For jQuery see this link: http://blog.oscarscode.com/dot-net/add-jquery-to-an-asp-net-web-application/ Cheers